# troubleshoot to create docker-machine

Tags: virtualbox, docker

I have problems launching docker properly (i use `--virtualbox-no-vtx-check`) even though I can't create a machine in docker it shows that :

```
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:02.257700 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

I use windows 10 Home, docker toolbox, VirtualBox with/without, NDIS5/NDIS6, core isolation off..

Anyone can help me plz